# Appending data to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to take multiple data files with the same number of columns into one continuous set of data. The x values are time and each subsequent datafile starts at the time of the  previous one finishing. So in theory if I do  some code like this:

```
    data = pd.read_csv(r"/PATH/out.txt", sep="\t")
    data2 = pd.read_csv(r"/PATH/out2.txt", sep="\t")
    data3 = pd.read_csv(r"/PATH/out3.txt", sep="\t")
    data4 = pd.read_csv(r"/PATH/out4.txt", sep="\t")
    data5 = pd.read_csv(r"/PATH/out5.txt", sep="\t")
    data6 = pd.read_csv(r"/PATH/out6.txt", sep="\t")
    data7 = pd.read_csv(r"/PATH/out7.txt", sep="\t")
    data8 = pd.read_csv(r"/PATH/out8.txt", sep="\t")

    print(data)

    data.append(data2, ignore_index=True)
    data.append(data3, ignore_index=True)
    data.append(data4, ignore_index=True)
    data.append(data5, ignore_index=True)
    data.append(data6, ignore_index=True)
    data.append(data7, ignore_index=True)
    data.append(data8, ignore_index=True)

    print(data)

    arr = data.to_numpy()
```

The print statement before and after should be different right? But it doesnt appear to append the other data files to the first one when I try. I must be missing something obvious, can anyone help with this?

The data files are in a 2 column format and look something like this (leftmost column is just the pandas indexing):

```
            Time(s)  CMASS(1,1,53)
    0     97.000229       0.999999
    1     98.000183       0.999999
    2     98.001122       0.999999
    3     98.200874       0.999999
    4     98.400703       0.999999
    ..          ...            ...
    209  119.700410       0.999999
    210  119.800410       0.999999
    211  119.900410       0.999999
    212  120.000400       0.999999
    213  120.000400       0.999999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pandas.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) method does not work not inplace by rather returns a new DataFrame. Thus, you need to save the return to your variable:

```
data = data.append(data2, ignore_index=True)
```

Yet, it would be more efficient in your case to use the [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method:

```
import glob
data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t") for f in glob.glob('/PATH/out*.txt')])
```

Comment: Thank you not sure why I didn't think of that haha!

Answer (score 2):

`DataFrame.append` returns a new object, it doesn't modify the dataframe that calls it. You would have to do:

```
data = data.append(data2)
```

Or you could just do:

```
data = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(path) for path in list_of_paths_to_csv)
```